# Nginx 301 rewrites using regex

Tags: redirect, nginx

I moved to a new software and now need to catch the old urls and rewrite them to the new ones.

Here is an example:

Old url: http://www.religiousforums.com/forum/neopagan-revival-religions-dir/19088-druid-horoscope-whats-your-sign.html
New url: https://www.religiousforums.com/threads/druid-horoscope-whats-your-sign.19088/

I tried this but it does not work:

```
    location ~* ^/forum/[^/]+/[0-9]+-[^\.]+\.html$ {
            rewrite [^/]+/([0-9]+)-[^\.]+\.html$ /threads/$1/ last;
    }
```

What am I missing here? I only need the id in the new url. The text is not important.

Answer (score -1):

Your capture group is wrong, you are capturing digits.

```
location ~* ^/forum/[^/]+/[0-9]+-[^.]+\.html$ {
    rewrite ^/forum/[^/]+/([0-9]+)-([^.]+)\.html$ /threads/$2.$1/ last;
}
```